# Memory leak - promises in a loop

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, promise, bluebird, appdynamics

My node app's CPU usage is gradually increasing. I have found that memory leaks are happening. Through AppDynamics, I have found that there is a significant amount of retained memory which keeps increasing over time under **processImmediate** call tree. As I drilled in, I found the problem was with **settlePromises** function.

[image: App Dynamics screen shot]

I want to get your opinion on one particular usage of promises I have been using. Looping of promises. Below is a sample function structure of such usage.

```
var dataArray = []; //list of jsons
var Promise = require('node-promise').Promise;

function doSomething(){
    try{
        var promises = [];
        //create function promises and push
        for(var i in dataArray){
            var usage = {};
            usage["user"] = dataArray[i].user;
            promises.push((function(ob){
                var log = extend({},ob);
                return executeFunction(log)}).bind(null,usage));
        }

        //loop and execute
        var respArray = [];
        return (promises.reduce(function(previous , current , index , array){
            try{
                return previous.then(function(resp){
                    if(resp != null)
                        respArray.push(resp);
                    if(promises.indexOf(current)==promises.length -1){
                        return current();
                    }
                    else{
                        return current();
                    }
                });
            }catch(ex){
                throw { ex : ex.stack};
            }
        },delay())).then(function(){
            return data;
        });
    }
    catch(ex){
        console.log(ex,ex.stack);
        throw { ex : ex.stack};
    }
}

function logTemplate(log){
    return models.Users.create(log).then(function(resp){
        return resp;
    },function(err){
        return err;
    });
}
```

The heap growth over an hour is plotted in the below picture

[image]

The above function has to perform a synchronous update with the objects in data array. Is there a chance of memory leak with this?

Comment: Yes. And also the chance is that its in your code, rather that in library. Start cutting stuff out - isolating the issue to the smallest reproducible code.

Comment: @c69 Thanks for the comment. Do you see any obvious mistakes with the above usage ? Maybe I will try to have one test case with this function, run it with setInterval and check the heap growth.

Comment: The part with `promises.push  /  promises.reduce` is an obvious code smell. Nested try..catch is code smell.  For..in is something that nobody uses since 2009 (original Crockford's book). If..else block inside of reduce is useless - both branches return same value.

Comment: @JLRishe Sry, my bad. Edited it now.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure whether it would be the cause of memory leaks, but your function definitely has a ton of unnecessary cruft that could be cleaned up with Bluebird's `Promise.mapSeries()` and other Bluebird helpers.

Doing so may very well help cut down on memory leaks.

`doSomething` function reduced to 8 lines:

```
function doSomething(){
    return Promise.delay(1000)  // <-- specify time
        .return(dataArray)
        .mapSeries(function (el) {
            return executeFunction({ user: el.user });
        })
        .filter(function (result) { 
            return result !== null; 
        });
}
```